# How to string-compare for a single space

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check whether a column has any values that are a single space character.

I initially thought that

```
WHERE my_column = ' '
```

would be sensible.  But no.  That will also match columns which have multiple spaces for some reason:

```
SELECT '    ' = ' '           => true
```

So I can use a regular express or hex encoding to test:

```
WHERE HEX(my_column) = '20'
WHERE my_column REGEXP '^\ $'
```

Both work.  But I suspect both (certainly the latter) will be quite inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [`BINARY` comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) of the two strings is required for an exact match

Under normal circumstances, trailing whitespace is not regarded in the comparison, but the `BINARY` operator forces it to be:

> BINARY also causes trailing spaces to be significant.

```
mysql> SELECT BINARY '   ' = ' ';
+--------------------+
| BINARY '   ' = ' ' |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
```

Incidentally, it isn't just whitespace-only comparisons that are affected by the trailing whitespace issue:

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc   ' = 'abc';
+------------------+
| 'abc   ' = 'abc' |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
```

...but...

```
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'abc   ' = 'abc';
+-------------------------+
| BINARY 'abc   ' = 'abc' |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
```

...and even more confusingly, leading whitespace *is* significant:

```
mysql> SELECT ' abc   ' = 'abc';
+-------------------+
| ' abc   ' = 'abc' |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
```

#### Regarding indexing:

`BINARY` will prevent an index from being used on the character column. However, [a note on the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) suggests that the index *will* be used if the `BINARY` operator is applied to the string literal side of the comparison as in:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `col` = BINARY 'string   '
```

Comment: Does using `BINARY` still uses indexes though?

Comment: I wonder why they don't ignore trailing 'G' characters, too? Or trailing '3's, or '6's, or 'x's...

Answer (score 3):

```
where my_column = ' ' and LENGTH(my_column) = 1
```

Comment: Its `LENGTH` in mysql not `len`.

Answer (score 0):

> **SELECT CASE WHEN COL_NAME='' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS SPACE_INDICATOR FROM Table_NAME  WHERE  LENGTH(COL_NAME)=1;**