# MySQL WHERE clause automatically trims trailing whitespace

Tags: mysql, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to string-compare for a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291098/how-to-string-compare-for-a-single-space)

Why in `MySQL` can I query

```
SELECT name
  FROM groups
 WHERE name =  'WEB    '
```

Noticed all the trailing whitespace. I would expect this to return no rows because the group `WEB` exists but not `WEB` with trailing whitespace. How can I force MySQL to query exactly and not automatically trim the trailing whitespace in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: A `BINARY` comparison is necessary. Have a look at the linked question.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim ??

Comment: Doesn't doing BINARY not use INDEXES though? Kills performance.

Comment: @Justin There's a note in the user docs "_The solution is to apply the binary operator to the constant, then the index is used_" as in `name = BINARY 'WEB   '`

Comment: @Justin I added a note to the linked answer about that...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski when I store the value do I have to specify BINARY? Because now I am getting not unique, even though I am trying to save WEB with trailing spaces, it thinks its the same as WEB with no trailing spaces.

Comment: @Justin A quick search turns up that the trailing space isn't accounted for by UNIQUE constraints. You may have to declare the column with utf8_bin as its charset.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is use `BINARY`.

```
SELECT name
  FROM groups
 WHERE name = BINARY 'WEB    '
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [LIKE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx) operator instead of '=' symbol

```
SELECT name FROM groups WHERE name like 'WEB    '
```

Another solution is you can use BINARY keyword also.

[Binary Function](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-BINARY-function-in-MySQL-for-case-sensitive-search--1103.php) :
          -This is the function that is provided by MySQL to compare columns byte-by-byte and can be used to perform case-sensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions;

As noted above, the CORRECT way of doing this would be via binary comparison. Typically this would not 'kill' performance as you put it; binary comparisons are typically very fast operations.

```
SELECT name
FROM groups
WHERE name = BINARY 'WEB   '
```

this would then concatenate 'WEB   ' to 'WEB'.

Other than that, you can look towards solutions in your front-end, if you are using one; such as using php to append "%20" in place of spaces, etc.  A more elegant solution would be to pre-load valid table names into an array, and compare against them for a valid match before running the query. However, I would think that just running the BINARY solution would be a lot better for your processing time.