# jOOQ: How to Create Select Query with MySQL “BINARY” Operator?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

### Question

How can I create any one of the following two (equivalent) MySQL statements with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)?

```mysql
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `col` = BINARY 'foobar   ';
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `col` = CAST('foobar   ' AS BINARY);
```

### Background

I’d like to compare arbitrary strings, possibly including (significant) trailing whitespaces. Unfortunately, MySQL ignores trailing whitespaces by default when comparing with `=`. As far as I’ve seen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13291179/1797912), such comparisons are only possible using [the `BINARY` operator in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-binary-op.html).

### What I’ve tried already

I’ve tried to use the [`DSL.cast()` method in jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/cast-expressions/):

```java
myDb.selectFrom(TBL)
  .where(TBL.COL
     .eq(DSL.cast("foobar   ", MySQLDataType.BINARY)))
  .fetchOne();
// → compiler error: “The method eq(String) in the type Field<String> is not
//   applicable for the arguments (Field<byte[]>)”

myDb.selectFrom(TBL)
  .where(DSL.cast(TBL.COL, MySQLDataType.BINARY)
     .eq("foobar   "))
  .fetchOne();
// → compiler error: “The method eq(byte[]) in the type Field<byte[]> is not
//   applicable for the arguments”

myDb.selectFrom(TBL)
  .where(DSL.cast(TBL.COL, MySQLDataType.BINARY)
     .eq(DSL.cast("foobar   ", MySQLDataType.BINARY)))
  .fetchOne();
// → runtime error: “org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from
//   foobar    (class java.lang.String) to class [B”
```

### Workaround

My last resort would be to change my query to use `LIKE` instead of `=`. That’d be a hack, though, as I would then have to always quote any wildcards in my string first and I would also face a performance penalty :-|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third example should work and is probably a bug, which I've registered as [Issue #3255](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3255):

```
myDb.selectFrom(TBL)
  .where(DSL.cast(TBL.COL, MySQLDataType.BINARY)
     .eq(DSL.cast("foobar   ", MySQLDataType.BINARY)))
  .fetchOne();
```

As always, if you're missing a feature in jOOQ, or if you've encountered a bug, you can resort to using plain SQL as documented here:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/

An example to work around In your case:

```
myDb.selectFrom(TBL)
  .where(TBL.COL
     .eq(DSL.field("BINARY ?", String.class, "foobar   ")))
  .fetchOne();
```

Or:

```
myDb.selectFrom(TBL)
  .where("{0} = BINARY {1}", TBL.COL, DSL.val("foobar   "))
  .fetchOne();
```